# Is there a way to have a generic Entity Framework Query(Expression expression) that handles any query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Maybe I'm off-base here and please tell me if I am. I'm trying to avoid complex queries all over my code to hit my database. At the same time, I don't want to have a repository API with every possible query listed in it for the rest of the app to use.

So...

Is it possible to write up a list of [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-7.0) objects, one for each needed query. These would have `Where().Include().ThenInclude().OrderBy()` in them and then where they are needed, at that location, then have a simple

```
dbContext.Authors.Query(MyComplicatedExpressionObjectToReturnAuthorsOfRomancNovelsWrittenSince2000)
```

And that returns the desired list. Critically where the expression is passed to the DB so the filtering occurs in the crafted SQL and not on the returned data.

I realize that this is more just moving the problem than solving it. And if writing an Expression by hand is difficult, then I've possibly made the system harder to use/debug. But if writing the `Expression` objects is straightforward, then this puts all the queries in a single location.

Can this be done? And if so, are there significant problems with this approach?

**UPDATE**

@RodrigoRodrigues gave an answer below that is so close, but still hitting a problem. I can get the extension to compile as follows:

```
public static IQueryable<Campaign> QueryByName<T>(this IQueryable<Campaign> source, string name)
{
    return source.Where(c => c.Name == name).Include(c => c.State).OrderBy(c => c.Id);
}
```

but not as:

```
public static IQueryable<Campaign> QueryByName<Campaign>(this IQueryable<Campaign> source, string name)
{
    return source.Where(c => c.Name == name).Include(c => c.State).OrderBy(c => c.Id);
}
```

This second case appears to be creating a new Campaign class inside this declaration that then hides the original Campaign class.

But the first declaration has an error when called:

```
var c2 = context.Campaigns.QueryByName(name);
```

My understanding of generics, etc. in C# is ok, not great. But based on that understanding I think this does need to be IQueryable to use it in the lambdas in the method. And I think the returned value needs to be IQueryable because that's what source... will return.

What am I missing in this?

Comment: The best you can do is `FunctionName(IQueryable<T> query) => query.Where(...)...` or `FunctionName(DbContext context)` as the `IQueryable` has a reference to the `DbContext` instance.

Comment: You could have just plain functions that take a `IQueryable<T>` input parameter. You can put them on a static class as extensions methods, similar to how Linq functions are organized.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues How do I then call the dbContext with that Expression? TIA

Comment: Same way you call `Where` or `Select` in any context, as both are just extension methods that take a queryable as input.

Comment: You cannot declare the method as `QueryByName<Campaign>`. The angle brackets notation `< >` are meant for generic type parameters, which are types to be resolved at runtime. Your method only works with `Campaign`, the type is known at compile time. So, you must declare your method as `IQueryable<Campaign> QueryByName(this IQueryable<Campaign> source, string name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a file with the static class that is the home of your extention methods.

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  public static class MyCustomQueries {
    public static IQueryable<T> MyComplicatedQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string genre, int since) {
        return source.Where(...).Select(...)...; // whatever implementation
    }

    // ... more extension methods
  }
}
```

Then, you will be able to use those extension methods automatically from anywhere in the same namespace. If you want to call them from other namespace, just import it.

```
using MyNamespace;

dbContext.Authors.MyComplicatedQuery("Romance", 2000);
```

More details on extension methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). You can also take a look on how Linq does that with `Where`, `Select` and such functions [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,a6b3f724cebbc54c).

Comment: First off, thank you. Second, I'm so close but still not working. I added an update to the question above. I'm hoping you can answer this last step. BTW - getting this to work will be very cool IMO. Great way to simplify all the queries in an app and keep them in one place.

Comment: If you are doing `this IQueryable<Campaign> source` as the extension parameter, you don't need to use generic type in the method `QueryByName<Campaign>`, because the type is known at compile time. Just do `IQueryable<Campaign> QueryByName(this IQueryable<Campaign> source, string name)`

Comment: Oh right. The <T> is the type to then substitute in in the other uses of T in the method. In fact, calling QueryByName<Campaign>() makes it all work too. But there's no need/use in passing that type in. Thanks for the help on this - I find this super cool.